# AwesomeWM: count number of elements in systray

Tags: linux, awesome-wm

I have my systray setup and works well. However, when it is empty it's keeping a big blank space and i'd like to get rid of that by hiding the tray with something like `visibility = false`. Is there a way to count the number of icons and hide it when it is 0?

I was expecting it to shrink when it is empty but doesn't
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the Answer (to the number of elements in systray) can be found in Awesome WM's Github Repo at `awesome/lib/wibox/widget/systray.lua`:

`num_entries` is the number of elements in your systray.

```
local capi = {
    awesome = awesome,
    screen = screen
}

local num_entries = capi.awesome.systray()
```

(I am not sure though, what happens if you have more than 1 systray)

I couldn't think of a nice way to hide your systray with this, but you could do it with `gears.timer`:

```
gears.timer {
    timeout   = 10, -- Time between checks
    call_now  = true,
    autostart = true,
    callback  = function()
        if capi.awesome.systray() == 0 then -- if systray has no elements
        your_systray_name.forced_height = 0 -- force heigt
        your_systray_name.forced_width = 0 -- and width to be zero
    end
    end
}
```

Did that help/resolve your question?

Comment: I don't understand. Tried to implement this but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share with me what you have tried/what didn't work/and maybe your systray code?

Comment: i can't access 'capi' variable from outside systray.lua

Comment: There is no `capi`. The code sample in the answer shows that this just uses the global `awesome` object, so you need `awesome.systray()` and not `capi.awesome.systray()`.

Comment: `(I am not sure though, what happens if you have more than 1 systray)` Systray is a singleton. You cannot have more than one. Because X11.